# Proof about intermediate value property and continuity

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I try to prove:

If $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ is increasing, that is if $x<y$ then $f(x) \le f(y)$ and if $f$ has the intermediate value property that is if $f(x) < K < f(y)$ then there exists $x<c<y$ with $f(c) = K$, then $f$ is continuous.

Please can you check my proof?

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ and $x \in [a,b]$. Consider $(f(x)-\varepsilon, f(x) + \varepsilon)$. By intermediate value property there is $x' \in f^{-1}(f(x)-\varepsilon, f(x))$ and $x'' \in f^{-1}(f(x), f(x) + \varepsilon)$. Because $f$ is increasing $x' < x < x''$. Now let $\delta = \min (|x-x'|,|x-x''|)$.

Comment: Looks good to me. You might want to clarify that you are proving that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @copper.hat Oh!! I forgot to write! thank you